# how to do calculations in price list page with reactjs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, frontend, react-forms

I am learning to react.I am recreating a webpage with react [webpage-link](https://www.sonycracker.com/order-items.php)

my question is, was it designed only with react if they have done so, how do calculations work? after submitting the selected items move them to the cart.
can someone please explain this?

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like that using [formik](https://www.npmjs.com/package/formik)

```
export function ProductsList(props) {
    const [products, setProducts] = useState();

    const formik = useFormik({
        initialValues: {},
        onSubmit: (values) => {
            // implement add to cart logic here
            // values object will contain product id as keys and quantity as values
        }
    });

    useEffect(() => {
        const products = [] // here should be products loading logic
        
        setProducts(products);
    }, []);

    if (!products) return <Loading />

    return (
        <form id="products-form" onSubmit={formik.handleSubmit}>
            <div id="products-list">
                {products.map(product => (<div id={product.id}>
                    {/* product card description */}
                    <input name="quantity" type="number" onChange={(e) => formik.setFieldValue(product.id, e.target.value)} />
                </div>))}
            </div>
            <div id="submit-button">
                <button type="submit">Submit</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    )
}
```